# Cannot get PHP code to Insert Credit Card Info into DB

Tags: php, html, sql

So, I'm really struggling to debug my code here.  I am trying to finish up a simple e-commerce website for books where a user inputs their credit card info after selecting a book they wish to purchase.

Here's my code:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) die("Could not connect to Database");

$card_num = $_POST['card_num'];
$exp_date = $_POST['exp_date'];
$card_type = $_POST['card_type'];
$cvv = $_POST['cvv_code'];
$cust_ID = $_SESSION['cust_ID'];
$purch_amount = $_POST['purch_amt'];

if(!$card_result)
{
     print( "<p>Could not save card information!</p>" ); 
     die( mysql_error() . "</body></html>" );
}
$purch_query = "SELECT Inventory_Amount FROM Product WHERE Product_ID=".$_SESSION['prod_ID']."";
$item_amount = $conn->query($purch_query);

if(!$item_amount)
{
    print( "<p>Could not execute query!</p>" ); 
    die( mysql_error() . "</body></html>" );
}

if($item_amount == 0 || $purch_amount > $item_amount)
{
    echo "<p><strong>Not Enough Product in Stock. <a href='books.php'>Click Here to continue shopping</a></strong></p>";
}   
else
{
    $card_query = "INSERT INTO CreditCard (Customer_ID, CreditCard_Number, CreditCard_Expiration_Date, CreditCard_Type, CreditCard_CVV_Code)
                        VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);";
    $card_result = $conn->prepare($card_query);
    $card_result->bind_param("isssi", $cust_ID, $card_num, $exp_date, $card_type, $cvv);
    $card_result->execute();

    if(!$card_result)
    {
         print( "<p>Could not save card information!</p>" ); 
         die( mysql_error() . "</body></html>" );
    }
    $new_amount = $item_amount - $purch_amount;
    $purch_query2 = "UPDATE Product SET Inventory_Amount=".$new_amount. " WHERE Product_ID=".$prodID."";
    $prod_result = $conn->query($purch_query2);

    if(!$item_amount)
    {
         print( "<p>Could not update inventory!</p>" ); 
         die( mysql_error() . "</body></html>" );
    }

}
```

Its picking up the "Could not save card information" error after I try to insert the card info into the database. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't save unencrypted credit card information--that's an extremely bad idea.

Comment: I think you might want to consider using a different DAL I personally prefer doctrine just because it works well with both zend and symphony and can be quickly included with composer.

Comment: I'm not too concerned about security here.  This is just for a non-security course.

Comment: Are you using MySql or MySqli?  Are you getting any errors from the query?

Comment: Why do you parameterize in some places and not in others? `mysql_error` won't help you, and might actually make your whole code block fail http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php. Is a CCV always an integer (Note leading `0`s are lost on integers)?

Comment: If you had error reporting working, I hope you'd be seeing a fatal error about an unknown function `mysql_error()` which was removed in PHP 7.0, released 3 years ago.

Comment: I've since removed mysql_error(). I had put it in there by mistake reading from a oldish text book that came out in 2016. That is NOT the issue here so if we can all stop pointing out my use of mysql_error(), that'd be great.

Comment: ...So you are just ignoring all other comments? Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53576852/edit and show us what you now have for code and what the current behavior is

Answer (score 0):

So, this was a stupid error on my part. The DB name wasn't correct.

Answer (score -2):

I would remove the semi-colon inside the quotes of this query.

From:

```
$card_query = "INSERT INTO CreditCard (Customer_ID, CreditCard_Number, CreditCard_Expiration_Date, CreditCard_Type, CreditCard_CVV_Code)
 VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);";
```

To:

```
$card_query = "INSERT INTO CreditCard (Customer_ID, CreditCard_Number, CreditCard_Expiration_Date, CreditCard_Type, CreditCard_CVV_Code)
 VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
```

A better way to test to see if the query added a row would be to check the response body of the query object to see if there was an affected row.

Like so:

```
$card_query = "INSERT INTO 
CreditCard (
  Customer_ID,
  CreditCard_Number,
  CreditCard_Expiration_Date,
  CreditCard_Type,
  CreditCard_CVV_Code
) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";

$card_result = $conn->prepare($card_query);
$card_result->bind_param("isssi", $cust_ID, $card_num, $exp_date, $card_type, $cvv);
$card_result->execute();

if($card_result->affected_rows === 0){

  print( "<p>Could not save card information!</p>" ); 
  die( mysql_error() . "</body></html>" );    

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: A better way to test is not use `mysql_error`. The semicolon wont make a difference.